# Spark SQL write integers as NaN on Oracle

Tags: oracle, scala, apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to write a Dataframe back into Oracle DB (I'm using Oracle Express 12c for development).

I'm writing the dataframe like this

```
val options = Map(
  "url" -> "jdbc:oracle:thin:username/password@host:1521:database",
  "driver" -> "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver",
  "dbtable" -> "myNewTab"
)
dataframe.write.format("jdbc").options(options).mode("overwrite").save()
```

My dataframe is string and integer columns with following schema

```
0 = {StructField@25373} "StructField(CustomerID,IntegerType,true)"
1 = {StructField@25374} "StructField(Gender,StringType,true)"
2 = {StructField@25375} "StructField(Age,IntegerType,true)"
3 = {StructField@25376} "StructField(Annual_Income__k__,IntegerType,true)"
4 = {StructField@25377} "StructField(Spending_Score__1_100_,IntegerType,true)"
```

After successfully running the spark job, when I inspect the written table on oracle I see that integer columns are all `NaN`!!!

So I tried to inspect the JDBC schema that could be generated for the table with `JdbcUtils.schemaString(dataframe, url, None)` and I see that integer columns are mapped to Oracle `NUMBER(10)` type

```
"CustomerID" NUMBER(10) , "Gender" VARCHAR2(255) , "Age" NUMBER(10) , "Annual_Income__k__" NUMBER(10) , "Spending_Score__1_100_" NUMBER(10)
```

Is there anything I'm missing here when using the Oracle JDBC driver with Spark?

Comment: your write operation looks good to me!. does your integer columns have values in dataframe ?

Comment: yes it does have integer values